# how to handle security error 2191 in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

When interacting with a RichEditableText component especially when i click copy  i get the following error message:

Error #2191: The Clipboard.generalClipboard object may only be written to as the result of user interaction, for example by a mouse click or button press.

The above error is reproducable sometimes in mozilla firefox browser. It is working fine in IE.
Can any one tell me how to handle that error in flex.

from google search i found that it is a bug http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/159638.

Comment: Can you show your code to create the error?

Comment: Since Flash 10 the security has been greatly increased. Some actions can now only be performed in callback handlers that handle events directly initiated by uses (Mouse events, keyboard events). Unfortunately if you want to copy to the clipboard you cannot do this in a callback handler that is for example a server result event as this is not initiated by the user directly.

Comment: @chrisdutz Can't we handle the run time exception in try catch block

Comment: @flextras.com  take any rich editable text component and run it in mozilla firefox that error is reproducable some times only